# Angular getting CORS No Access-Control-Allow Origin when references css file on a https server

Tags: css, angular, cross-domain, access-control

I have an Angular 5 application with Web api back-end ,  however all I am looking to do is reference a CSS file on a production server.

What can I do to avoid the cross origin issue   ( cors is enabled on the web api,  but its not the web api , its simply a CSS file on that IIS server website.

> Access to Font at 'https://prodserver/Content/Styles/fonts/icomoon.ttf?53j0gm' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' ...

I was attempted to use CORS in my angular application,  and its nothing to do with web api cors, and i'm not using node ,

This is simply CSS ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the web server for CORS. The error you included is not for CSS, but for fonts. Fonts are subject to CORS restrictions on some browsers

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CORS on BE side

For Web Api check

[Web Api Cors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Comment: It is not on Web api  ,    index.html is referencing  `<link href="https://prodserver/Content/Styles/custom/dist/icisng-main-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`